# change ggplot2 y-axis values

Tags: r, ggplot2

Please help me. I have the following data in R: I have values of three groups of organisms from day 0 to day 7 which represent the mean of populations for these groups for each day.

Here is my data:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15-XXT6jOSKZs0FS14FScnHMm0Qd19N-x/edit#gid=377184551

And was trying to follow an example on the following page; https://statisticsglobe.com/plot-all-columns-of-data-frame-in-r, but the graphs I get give data value on the y axis and also the ploted lines are joined. I would like to have separate lines for each of the groups (the three groups) and also have a scale on the y axis instead of plot values. Plotting individual values for each of the groups gives me the same values on the y-axis instead of a scale. I would however like the y-axis values to begin with values of Day 0 and keep ascending upwards into until Day 7 unlike the mixed case I have right now. The code I used is as follows:

**Data and code**

```
growth <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
               day = c("Day 0","Day 1","Day 2",
                       "Day 3","Day 4","Day 5","Day 6","Day 7"),
         wild_type = c(6, 9.8, 69.53, 84.67, 99.33, 145.33, 147.33, 121.8),
           t7_cas9 = c(6, 8.57, 68.83, 85.5, 98.25, 144.67, 137.5, 120.5),
              ip6k = c(6, 6.5, 49.67, 56, 70.5, 127.5, 123.67, 111.33)
)

data_ggp <- data.frame(x = growth$day,                  
  y = c(growth$wild_type, growth$t7_cas9, growth$ip6k),
  group = c(rep("Wild_Type", nrow(growth)), 
            rep("T7_Cas9", nrow(growth)), 
            rep("IP6K-+", nrow(growth))))

ggp <- ggplot(data_ggp, aes(x, y, col = group, group = 1)) +
       geom_line()
ggp

p1 <- ggp + facet_grid(group ~ .)
p1
```

[image]

[image]

However, what I would like to have is:

[image]

[image]

Comment: No access to data!

Comment: Does it resolve when you remove `group = 1` or replace it with `group = group`? `group = 1` is telling ggplot2 you want the line segments to be part of a single series.

Comment: Oh, also your y axis data was imported as character or factor types, not as numeric, so ggplot is plotting it in alphabetical order, surely not what you intended. Use `as.numeric(y = c(growth$Wild_Type, ...)` when defining your data.

Comment: Hello @TarJae, I am sorry I have provided data access now.

Comment: Hello @JonSpring, removing `group = 1` does not help but adding `group = group`does help with the first problem. I now have distinct lines but the y axis is still plotted in alphabetical order. Adding the solution to the final comment gives the following error "Error in as.numeric(y = c(growth$Wild_Type, growth$T7.Cas9, growth$IP6K...)) : 
  supplied argument name 'y' does not match 'x'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for such a solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Day) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Day, y = value, group=name, color = name))+
  geom_line(size=1)
```

[image]

**AND with facet**

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Day) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Day, y = value, group=name, color = name))+
  geom_line(size=1)+
  facet_grid(name ~ .)
```

[image]

data:

```
df <- structure(list(Day = c("Day 0", "Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3", "Day 4", 
"Day 5", "Day 6", "Day 7"), Wild_Type = c(6, 9.8, 69.53, 84.67, 
99.33, 145.33, 147.33, 121.8), T7_Cas9 = c(6, 8.57, 68.83, 85.5, 
98.25, 144.67, 137.5, 120.5), IP6K = c(6, 6.5, 49.67, 56, 70.5, 
127.5, 123.67, 111.33)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I was indeed looking for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 7, 1), limits = c(0, 7), labels = c())`

I guess you could play around with the labels argument; also not sure about your data, but some transformations (eg log) may help to separate the data better!

Comment: Hello @ckreitzer. Thanks for the solution but it didn't work. I added the line you gave but it returned the following error : "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale".